# ClassCastException from View objects in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, classcastexception

In Android Studio, when i try to run my project i get a `ClassCastException` as following:

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout`

when the View object is 100% RelativeLayout and not EditText.
The problem occurs on another View element if i comment out the above-related code..

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, i have tried editing the XML file and change the ID, i have tried deleting the XML file and restarting Android Studio and then make a new XML file, all that to no avail.

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT**
When i add new views to the xml, with id that i never used, somehow the activity before it gets nulls on its own (and totally seperate) xml file.. this is weird because theres no reason why a simple view on a different xml file should impact another xml that is loaded even before it..

**EDIT2**
I inspected `View rl = activityView.findViewById(R.id.notification);` and found out that it gets etMessage which is another view element in the same XML and is infact an `EditText` type view.

The code before the exception occurs:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setInitialView();
}

private void setInitialView() {
    RelativeLayout frame = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_frame);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View activityView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.chat, null,false);
    frame.removeAllViews();
    frame.addView(activityView);

    chatMap.put("Public", new ArrayList<ChatMessageBox>());

    // move the notification layout outside the screen
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.notification);
    TranslateAnimation moveAnim = new TranslateAnimation(
            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0, TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0,
            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0, TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1);
    moveAnim.setDuration(0);
    moveAnim.setFillAfter(true);
    rl.startAnimation(moveAnim);
}
```

This activity's parent XML, which is loaded with setContentView in its onCreate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  Making the drawer layout the root view -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_frame"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</RelativeLayout>


<!-- The ListView to be displayed when the drawer layout is active -->
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And the XML that has the appropriate view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Making the drawer layout the root view -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/chat_relative_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bSendMessage"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/chat_bg" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chatWindowContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bSendMessage"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_send" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etMessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bSendMessage"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bSendMessage"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/text"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:imeOptions="actionNone"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxLines="4"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false" />

    <!-- the desired element -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/notification"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_upload"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNotification"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="New Message Recieved"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Error log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.raad/com.example.raad.activities.ChatActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout
                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2351)
                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout
                                     at com.example.raad.activities.ChatActivity.setInitialView(ChatActivity.java:336)
                                     at com.example.raad.activities.ChatActivity.onCreate(ChatActivity.java:43)
                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1146)
                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315)
                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403) 
                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165) 
                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373) 
                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391) 
                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833) 
                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 
                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post code in your activity or fragment, or place where findViewById is used

Comment: Post your code and error log

Comment: Its in onCreate, and there isnt anything going on before that, so that code is irrelevant.

Comment: You have probably messed up something, which is why you are getting the exception.

Comment: I edited in all your requests. @NongthonbamTonthoi to be honest i dont think i messed something up in the code, because of that second problem that appears if i edit out that code, because im 99.999% sure i havent changed anything that should affect that, or even anything at all, since i last ran the project and everything worked fine. So i think its actually an Android Studio type problem like R not updating or something.

Comment: You are getting the activity_frame but maybe it still doesn't exists...

Comment: You xml file doesn't have the root relative layout closing tag.

Comment: It has it, it just didnt show because of the indentation, fixed it.
@antonicg if it doesnt exist why would it think that its EditText rather than Null?

Comment: Maybe is getting from other activity or something is messed up like @NongthonbamTonthoi said. But, if the activity still doesn't has a view, how are you getting one?

Comment: This activity extends another activity that does setContentView, so then when this activity runs, i shouldnt do setContentView because i want the parent view, and add items to it like i do in setInitialView

Comment: post that other parent activity and the `xml` which contains `activity_frame`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was probably with the cache of the application in the device itself.
I ran the application on a different device and there was no issue, so i cleared the data and cache from the device (Settings -> Apps) and uninstalled the app (just uninstalling didnt work), and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Change your onCreate like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yourLayoutXmlName);
    setInitialView();
}
```

**Edit:**

Try changing this line:

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.notification);
```

to

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) activityView.findViewById(R.id.notification);
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I dont want to setContentView, because this layout is loaded into another layout, mind the first lines in setInitialView

Comment: I did, it changes nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
R.id.activity_frame
```

does not exists in your xml file. Try to resolve this.
And post the complete code.

Comment: activity_frame is in another xml, which is loaded by this activity's parent, setContentView in onCreate, and this xml is added into that activity_frame

Comment: @TomerSomething R.id.notification check this id in your R.java file it may refer to a edittext previously.